# How can I position two divs below one div so they fill their container

Tags: html, css

I have three divs inside a container div. I need the top div to fill the whole width, and the bottom to to each fill half.

I've tried it using percentages but the bottom two divs keep appearing one on top of the other.

**Markup:**

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">DIV1</div>
    <div id="div2">DIV2</div>
    <div id="div3">DIV3</div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    border:1px solid black;
}

#div1{
     float:left; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}

#div2{
     clear:both;
     float:left;  
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
}

#div3{
     float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[See on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/639fzg65/5/)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It works without the border. But unfortunately I need the border to stay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define this `box-sizing:border-box;`

because you define your `#div2` or `#div3` width `50%` with border `solid 1px`

than your `#div2` or `#div3` width is `50%+border-left-width+border-right-width`

**50%+1px+1px**

```
div{
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

more about [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: Here is an article if someone wants to read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. fixed it for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/639fzg65/9/

I gave the div surrounding the 3 divs a width of 100%

```
#container{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. i pasted the original fiddle.

Comment: But he said, under comments of his question, that he needs the border to stay :)

Comment: @RFLdev The other border is still there, but the inner ones have gone.

Comment: Yeah, when i was posting this, the comment wasn't under the question. So i didn't knew that then.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you..

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1">DIV1</div>
  <div id="div2">DIV2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV3</div>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this same answer was posted by Rohit Azad 8 minutes before you.

Comment: if the problem is solved than the answer can be same it can be coincidence